# Basic CKEditor/JQuery event onChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, jquery-events

I'm using CKEditor on a web page with JQuery. The challenge it to allow the user to insert tokens in the text. The tokens come from a select box. So the user can write:

> Hello, %first-name%,
> Our records indicate your current mailing address is %current-mailing-address% .......

The idea being, once the form is posted, the tokens will get parsed for every body in the 'To' list and then personalized emails will be sent.

My approach is roughly as follows:

On the JQuery select box `onChange`, I'll ask CKEditor instance what is the current caret position, then insert the token at that position.

The textarea is defined as:

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="100" id="wysiwyg" name="emailText"></textarea>
```

CKEditor Jquery binding:

```
var config = {
        skin:'v2',
        toolbar : 'Basic'
    };
$('#wysiwyg').ckeditor(config);
```

`wysiwyg` is the TEXTAREA's id.

I wanted to test some basic event functionality and tried the following but none seems to be working:

```
$('#wysiwyg').on( 'click', function() {alert('honum'); }); // Does not work

var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.wysiwyg;
$(editor).on('click', function(evt) {alert('honum'); }); // Does not work

var element = CKEDITOR.document.getById( 'wysiwyg' ); // No luck here either
element.on( 'click', function( ev ) {
    alert('hohum');
});
```

Can anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong? What is the right way to proceed with this problem, any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The ck editor that you actually input text into is not the same textarea that has the ID.

Comment: Shouldn't `var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.wysiwyg;` get that ck editor?

Comment: No, that's an instance of a the `CKEDITOR` class. It is an object. The actual editor is an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why but the following worked:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.wysiwyg.on('paste', function() {
    alert ('Hohum');
});
```